# SCR to OSGi R6 Annotations issue

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

I am migrating some SCR annotations based code base to OSGi R6.

The current code uses scr annotations and fields which are not available in R6.

For example: `@references`  and `referenceInterface` are not supported in R6

```
@Component
@References({
  @Reference(
  referenceInterface = SomeFactory.class,
  policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
  cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE)
})

@Service
public class SomeResolverImpl implements SomeResolver { }
```

Comment: What issue are you having here?

Answer (score 0):

The OSGi R6 annotation set does indeed have a `@Reference` annotation. See section 112.13.8 of the OSGi R6 Compendium Specification. Or, here is a [direct link](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference) to the online R7 specification.

You should place this annotation either on the field or the method that you wish to bind to the service reference.

Comment: I am asking about @references annotation (which is added at class level). Please go through this class : https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-guides/blob/master/simple-search-guide/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/aem/sample/simple/search/predicates/impl/PredicateResolverImpl.java

Comment: What are you asking about it? In OSGi annotations you have to put the `@Reference` annotation on the injected field or method. This makes much more sense, BTW!